# jQuery - How to find if variable "jQuery" is a valid jQuery object/library

Tags: javascript, jquery

We know that generally either `$` or `jQuery` is a JavaScript variable in which entire jQuery library lives.

Say if there's a JavaScript code:

```
function abc() {
    $=1;
    jQuery='foo';
    $('p').hide(); //won't work
    jQuery('p').show(); //won't work
}
```

In this case; how can we check if `jQuery` or `$` actually holds a valid jQuery library? or is there some other value assigned to these two variables? I need to know this for validation purposes. There should be something like:

```
if(typeof $==="jQuery")
```

Is there any method to know this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can "sniff" the value, but it's technically pretty difficult to be absolutely certain. If you're not worried that code on a page may be trying to fool you, well then sniffing is fine :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check for [the `jquery` property](http://api.jquery.com/jquery-2/):

```
if (jQuery && jQuery.fn && jQuery.fn.jquery) {
    // Yep, it's jQuery
}
```

If you need to allow for the case where jQuery may not be loaded at all, you'll want to amend that slightly:

```
if (typeof jQuery === "function" && jQuery.fn && jQuery.fn.jquery) {
    // Yep, it's jQuery
}
```

Comment: @cookiemonster: Well blow me down. Thanks! *(That's very useful to know, I can stop feeling guilty for using it... Not sure how I could miss that.)*